# Simplifying a query with a nested query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to remove the need for a nested query if I can from my query below, but I'm struggling to work out how.

This is the schema:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[expiration]
(
    [batch_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fruit_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [store_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [expiration_date] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[fruits]
(
    [fruit_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fruit_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (1, 3, 4, CAST(N'2021-11-25' AS Date))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (1, 2, 2, CAST(N'2021-11-22' AS Date))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (1, 5, 3, CAST(N'2021-11-30' AS Date))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (2, 2, 7, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (2, 3, 2, CAST(N'2021-12-12' AS Date))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (1, 1, 5, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[expiration] ([batch_number], [fruit_number], [store_number], [expiration_date]) 
VALUES (2, 1, 6, CAST(N'2021-11-28' AS Date))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[fruits] ([fruit_number], [fruit_name]) 
VALUES (1, N'banana')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[fruits] ([fruit_number], [fruit_name]) 
VALUES (2, N'apple')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[fruits] ([fruit_number], [fruit_name]) 
VALUES (3, N'pear')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[fruits] ([fruit_number], [fruit_name]) 
VALUES (4, N'peach')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[fruits] ([fruit_number], [fruit_name]) 
VALUES (5, N'strawberry')
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT
    fruit_number, 
    MAX(expirationDate) as expirationDate
FROM
    (SELECT
        f.fruit_number,
        CASE
            WHEN e.expiration_date is NULL AND e.fruit_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS expirationDate
    FROM
        expiration AS e
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        fruits AS f ON f.fruit_number = e.fruit_number
    WHERE
        f.fruit_number IS NOT NULL) t
GROUP BY
    fruit_number
ORDER BY
    fruit_number
```

It produces this result set:

| fruit_number | expirationDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |

The resultset is what I'm after, but it's ugly having the nested query. Is it possible to do this without the nested query? An online query analyser (https://www.eversql.com/sql-query-optimizer/) said to move the sub-query into a temp table and query against that, but isn't just doing the same thing in more steps?

Comment: Can You also explain what exactly is 1 and 0 in result set ? I could analize this nested query but i don't want to get it wrong.

Comment: _WHERE f.fruit_number IS NOT NULL_ That negates your FULL OUTER JOIN and turns it into a regular right join.

Comment: More Steps do not matter.what matter is performance ,if it involve more step then be it,if it involve less step then its better.So onlie suggesation was ok.Or any of the below query performance is better then it more good.Why will Fruit table contain fruit_number which do not exists expiration ? Give example.So i think it should be inner join al together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first change I would make is with your joins. It makes no sense to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` then put in a where clause that says `f.fruit_number IS NOT NULL`. This means that every row must have a record in `fruits`, so your query would make more sense as `SELECT .. FROM fruits AS f LEFT JOIN expiration AS e ON e.fruit_number = f.fruit_number`.

You can also remove the subquery by placing your case expression directly within the `MAX` function:

```
SELECT  f.fruit_number, 
        f.fruit_name,
        expirationDate = MAX(CASE WHEN e.expiration_date IS NULL 
                                    AND e.fruit_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    dbo.fruits AS f
        LEFT JOIN dbo.expiration AS e
            ON e.fruit_number = f.fruit_number
GROUP BY f.fruit_number, f.fruit_name
ORDER BY f.fruit_number;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=15874c8d52d8dae3a76b2d73fba3bd0b)**

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I believe it gets you what you wanted:

```
SELECT t1.fruit_number
, CASE WHEN MIN(ISNULL(expiration_date, '1/1/1900')) = CAST('1/1/1900' as date) and t2.fruit_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END expirationDate
FROM fruits t1 
LEFT JOIN expiration t2 on t1.fruit_number = t2.fruit_number
GROUP BY t1.fruit_number, t2.fruit_number
ORDER BY t1.fruit_number
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are overcomplicating this. Assuming that `fruit_number` is unique in `fruits`, there is no need for a `group by`, instead use an `exists`

```sql
SELECT
  f.fruit_number, 
  f.fruit_name,
  expirationDate = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM dbo.expiration AS e
                       WHERE e.fruit_number = f.fruit_number
                         AND e.expiration_date IS NULL
                     ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.fruits AS f
ORDER BY f.fruit_number;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a9258677cfd1c9419c2d687c1e60e49)